# get duplicate rule specify in crm plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4

I'm creating 2 duplicate rule for contact in CRM 2011.

1. duplicate rule for number phone
2. duplicate rule for email

I create plugin on create or update contact **I need to get name the rule detected**

for example :

contact 1 : `full_name = Philip Richardson ; email = prichardson4@usnews.com;`
contact 2 : `full_name = Diana Jackson     ; email = prichardson4@usnews.com;`

contact 1 already exists and contact 2 new contact created
duplicate rule detected 2 for the same email
**I need to get name the rule detected in the plugin**
Any ideas ?

thanks.

Comment: this question is very confusing.  you have 2 duplicate detection rules, so the 2nd one is being triggered.  Are you trying to only trigger the duplicate window when **both** conditions are met?  I also don't understand what you are asking about plugins or how that is related to duplicate detection.

Comment: hi Joseph Duty.    I have 2 duplicate detection rules so the 2nd one is being triggered.    I need to get this duplicate rule.     how can do that ?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there is a language barrier here, I still don't understand your question

Comment: So everything works but you want to know the CONTACT NAME of the one already existing on CRM ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard duplicate detection process built into the system, you can monitor the duplicate detection jobs from the Duplicate Detection button in the Workplace module (standard sitemap). This will tell you what duplicates were detected, why, and let you merge them.